# Equivalent observers in Shiny apps but different behaviors

Tags: r, shiny, observers

The difference between the two Shiny apps is that the first one includes

```r
  observeEvent(
    input$alert,
    {
      flag(TRUE)
    }
  )
```

while this code is replaced with the following code in the second one:

```r
  observeEvent(
    list(input$alert, input$X),
    {
      flag(TRUE)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE
  )
```

where `input$X` is always `NULL`.

However the two apps have a different behavior (click several times on the button). Why? I don't understand the behavior of the second one.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    actionButton(
      inputId = "button",
      label = "ALERT"
    )
  )
)

server1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  flag <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(
    input$button,
    {
      confirmSweetAlert(
        inputId = "alert",
        title = "ALERT",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    input$alert,
    {
      flag(TRUE)
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    flag(),
    {
      flag(NULL)
      sendSweetAlert(
        title = "ALERT 2",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )
  
}


server2 <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  flag <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  observeEvent(
    input$button,
    {
      confirmSweetAlert(
        inputId = "alert",
        title = "ALERT",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )

  observeEvent(
    list(input$alert, input$X),
    {
      flag(TRUE)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE
  )

  observeEvent(
    flag(),
    {
      flag(NULL)
      sendSweetAlert(
        title = "ALERT 2",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server1)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different behaviour is caused by the fact, that `list(NULL, NULL)` is not `NULL` (resulting in `flag` being set to `TRUE`):

```
> is.null(list(NULL, NULL))
[1] FALSE
```

and `observeEvent` uses `ignoreNULL = TRUE` by default.

Setting `ignoreNULL = FALSE` in `server1` results in the same behaviour as shown for `server2`:

```
server1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  flag <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(
    input$button,
    {
      confirmSweetAlert(
        inputId = "alert",
        title = "ALERT",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    input$alert,
    {
      flag(TRUE)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    flag(),
    {
      flag(NULL)
      sendSweetAlert(
        title = "ALERT 2",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )
  
}
```

As an alternative use `c(input$alert, input$X)` instead of `list(input$alert, input$X)` in server2:

```
> is.null(c(NULL, NULL))
[1] TRUE
```

---

```
server2 <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  flag <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$button,
    {
      confirmSweetAlert(
        inputId = "alert",
        title = "ALERT",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent({c(input$alert, input$X)},
    {
      flag(TRUE)
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    flag(),
    {
      flag(NULL)
      sendSweetAlert(
        title = "ALERT 2",
        type = "error"
      )
    }
  )
  
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But I still don't understand the behavior of `server2` in my post.

Comment: I thought that `flag(TRUE)` would not be executed because of the `ignoreInit = TRUE`, no?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent `ignoreInit = TRUE` prevents the observer from being run directly after it was created - try setting it to `FALSE`.

Comment: Yes, so it is not being run, so why `flag()` is `TRUE`?

Comment: And why the alternating behavior of server2 ? (alert 2 - alert1 then alert 2 - alert2 - alert1 then alert2 - ...).

Comment: The explanation for `flag()` being set to `TRUE` is what I am showing above. Both alerts are being fired in the same reactive cycle - not sure if `shinyWidgets` devs created a intended reaction to this.

Comment: I obviously understand that `list(NULL, NULL)` is not `NULL`. But that does not imply that the body of the observer is executed, since `ignoreInit = TRUE`, and this is the `init`.

Comment: When setting `ignoreInit = FALSE` the `oberver` is first executed/initialized without pushing a button - else it needs user interaction - that's the difference - not sure what else to explain here.

Comment: My point is that `list(NULL, NULL)` is not `NULL` but ***it doesn't matter*** : it is ignored because `ignoreInit = TRUE`. What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm maybe I see now: when the button is pressed, the event handler of the second observer is still 'list(NULL, NULL)`, but this time it is not ignored because this is not the initialization. Right?

Comment: It is ignored on app start - not on user update. Edit: Exactly right!

Comment: Ok so my previous comment is right. That means an observer can react while there is no change to what it observes. Subtle.

Comment: Let me put it like this: via `ignoreInit` we have the possibility to postpone the first check of the event expression.